# Control compilation of framework api in release or debug mode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have vendor framework added to bridging header. I want to use framework only in debug mode. am using 2 header files one for debug one for release. In the release mode am not using that framework but i have the code in the application accessing that framework api. How should i stop the release mode compiling the api? **I added macros #if DEBUG to the api but still its compilation fails.**

Comment: What do you mean that it's still failing?

Comment: compilation failing. can we achieve stopping the compilation of a framework api based on debug or release mode.

Answer (score 0):

conditional compiling works by adding flag in active compilation conditions.
created sample for reference.
SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS = DEBUG

https://github.com/sreexamus/ActiveCompilation